# How to load a section of the page using ajax when load page?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to use ajax to load some data from database when the page loads. But it won't work or show the data.

my code on controller side.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? respondentId)
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetIntroParagraph(int? id)
{
    int id = id?? 111;
    Paragraph p= ParagraphDb.GetParagraghByRespondentId(id);
    return Content(p.Introduction);
}
```

And my code on the view,

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var data = undefined;
        $.load(@Url.Action("GetIntroParagraph","Landing"),data,function(result) {
            $('#paragraph').append(result);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="paragraph"></div>
```

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: What if any errors do you get in the browser console? Does `p.Introduction` have a value?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  'p.Introduction' doesn't have a value. I set a breakpoint. It won't go into the GetIntroParagraph method.

Comment: So what error do you get in the browser? (and your missing quotes around `'@Url.Action("GetIntroParagraph","Landing")'`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thanks for the tips for checking the error in console, now I got it working. I should use $.get or $.post, it won't recognize $.load.

Comment: You have the wrong syntax for `.load()` - it needs to be `$(someElement).load(url, data);` - refer [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answers, here is the solution I found myself.

1.I have to reference jquery file in front.
2.use $.post instead of $.load

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script>
$(function () {

    var data = undefined;
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetIntroParagraph","Landing")', data, function (result) {
        $('#paragraph').append(result);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `.load()` - `$('#paragraph').load('@Url.Action("GetIntroParagraph","Landing")';` (see comments to the question)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I try to use $('#paragraph').load('@Url.Action("GetIntroParagraph","Landing")', data, function (result) {
            $('#paragraph').append(result);
        }); somehow it shows the result data two times. That's weird.

Comment: Read the previous comment - the code is just `$('#paragraph').load('@Url.Action("GetIntroParagraph","Landi‌​ng")';` (exactly)